# Baseado em opinião está sendo usada corretamente?

Tags: debate, sinalização, fechamento

Minha pergunta é pelo fato de perceber que alguma *palavras chaves* disparam automaticamente um: **isso é  baseado em opinião** e devo sinalizar.

**Há uma diferença muito grande entre:**

- saber a qual opinião pessoal para resolver um problema
- como um problema pode ser resolvido de forma eficiente, levando em conta as limitações da linguagem usada, configurações, servidor...

Vou dar dois exemplos **fictícios** para ilustrar. Na segunda pergunta pode-se entender que é baseado em opinião, mas algumas formas se destacam por serem eficientes, logo não é a opinião pessoal, mas sim levando em conta vários fatores da linguagem.

**Queria fomentar um debate sobre como estão sendo tratadas essas sinalizações.**

---

*Pergunta:* Como verificar se um arquivo existe?
*Resposta:* `stream_resolve_include_path`, `file_exists` ou `is_file`

Uma pergunta como essa, pode receber uma resposta simples com os 3 exemplos citados, sem explanação profunda dos prós de cada método e ser aceita como resposta. Certamente vai depender de outras respostas para completar a explicação.

Entretanto a resposta resolve uma dúvida, mesmo que superficialmente.

---

*Pergunta:* Qual a melhor forma de verificar se um arquivo existe?
*Resposta:* A função tal apresenta melhor desempenho por isso e aquilo...

Já essa pergunta certamente receberia justificativas adequadas para a escolha do melhor método. Provavelmente teria respostas em cenários diferentes tornando a explanação bem mais profunda.

Comment: Fico com a impressão que uma "P: Qual a melhor forma?" vai ter uma "R: Depende de tais circunstâncias...". Já uma "P: Como fazer isto em tal circunstância" vai ter uma "R: A melhor forma é..." . . . mas não sei se isso é lógica circular :)

Comment: É exatamente essa questão. :) As vezes a *tal circunstância* pode ser genérica e sem tanta importância.

Comment: @PapaCharlie nesses casos o melhor a fazer é tentar "desgeneralizar". Porque uma pergunta: "Qual a melhor forma" sem um caso mais ou menos especifico, vai acabar por obter respostas baseadas em opiniões como já vi muito por ai... A sua pergunta até pode estar muito boa e muito especifica, mas algumas palavras chave como "qual a melhor" acabam por gerar respostas baseadas em opiniões. A não ser que especifiques mais um bocado o problema.

Comment: @JorgeB. Vejo outras questões que poderiam ser sinalizadas de forma mais flexível. Na minha última pergunta eu expliquei que era sobre a linguagem e mesmo assim trataram como baseada em opiniões. Aproveitei o momento para abrir um 'meta' e debater.

Comment: Qual pergunta papa?

Comment: A [minha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/34493/13412)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Concordo que certas palavras-chaves disparam um comportamento automatizado de fechar como *baseada em opiniões*, especialmente "melhor", tipicamente em "qual a melhor forma de...". Muitos usuários removem esse tipo de expressão das perguntas justamente para tentar salvá-las disso – e talvez até o tiro saia pela culatra, reforçando em alguns a idéia de que basta uma expressão assim para justificar o fechamento.

Na realidade, esse motivo e o *ampla demais* são os mais difíceis de se julgar. Considerando seus exemplos, nenhuma das duas perguntas deveria ser fechada, e na prática as duas são idênticas. É muito importante levar em conta o contexto. As perguntas são sobre PHP (correto?), e em PHP existe um número limitado de maneiras de se verificar se um arquivo existe (isso aliás é válido em qualquer linguagem). Portanto é possível responder com algumas ou mesmo todas as opções, com mais ou menos detalhes, com ou sem testes e argumentos baseados em *performance*.

O julgamento deve ser pautado principalmente pelo conteúdo e pelo contexto das perguntas, e não pela forma. Se o exemplo fosse outro, eu talvez julgasse que ambas devessem ser fechadas, como *amplas demais*, *baseadas em opinião* ou mesmo *não são claras*, dependendo do caso.

Comment: Pois é, "qual a melhor forma de...", na minha opinião, eu considero como alguém em busca de uma solução otimizada, não a minha opinião pessoal. Mas parece que ao ler - *qual a melhor[...]* - faz um bloqueio na leitura da questão e ignora todo resto do contexto.

Comment: bfavaretto o problema é que muitas vezes, mesmo a pergunta não sendo baseada em opiniões, o "qual a melhor forma" acaba por gerar muitas respostas baseadas em opiniões. Não será motivo para fechar? Fica a pergunta.

Comment: Isto **talvez** seja vício do SO. E um vício criado pelo sistema. Não sei como está hoje mas o próprio sistema ajudava indicar que a pergunta era baseada em opinião quando encontrava certas palavras durante a escrita. Eu entendo que se a pessoa pede qual é o melhor, nem sempre é o que ela quer. Se for o que ela quer (não é o caso dos exemplos citados), é baseado em opinião. Mas eu acho também que a pergunta poderia ser mais clara quanto a isso. Eu não fecho baseado em palavras e sim o que eu entendo que é a pergunta. Se eu entender errado (diferente de não entender), a culpa é da pergunta.

Comment: Lembrando que eu acho que eu acho que qualquer pessoa que possa ajudar uma pergunta ficar menos ambígua, menos clara, deva fazer. Salvar uma pergunta boa que está em uma forma ruim é desejável. E é claro que se a pessoa não consegue ajudar, deve esperar que outro o faço e se abster para não estragar ainda mais.

Comment: Só para esclarescer uma coisa que escrevi acima: "Se eu entender errado (diferente de não entender), a culpa é da pergunta". É claro que a culpa pode ser minha, mas não tem como eu saber disto. Na hora de decidir estou sozinho. Se eu **entendi** algo que me faz decidir por fechar uma pergunta, não tem como eu saber que estou errado. E aí que entra a responsabilidade do texto original. Se ele me engana, como eu posso ser o culpado? Claro que se o texto é confuso ou não entendo do assunto, ou peço esclarecimento ou não faço nada.